# Add subprocess calls in a for loop

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like my script to iterate over 4 elements of a list. I am using 
 a subprocess call. I'm not sure how to fix the code I have to do so.

```
for i in sortedList: 
    subprocess.call(['python','/path/to/script/script.py', i:4]])
```

The `i:4` part is where I am having trouble.I want the 4 elements in my list to be inputs into script.py.

The script is supposed to take in a picture pic.png, make it grayscale, and output new.pic.png as a black and white image. I would ultimately like the script to be run over 4 different images and output 4 new images (that are now in grayscale).

Comment: simply `i` should be enough, or not? Each time subprocess will call the script with a different argument

Comment: If you want each element in the list to have its own function call,  remove the `:4`

Comment: Just to confirm: when you say you want to "iterate over 4 elements of a list", do you mean that the list has four elements, and you want to iterate over its values one-by-one? Or do you mean that the list has more than four elements, and you want to iterate over its values four at a time?

Comment: @Kevin, I would just like to iterate over the 4 elements in my list. Please let me know if that didnt answer your question!

Comment: Let's put it in a different way. How many arguments `'/path/to/script/script.py'` needs?

Comment: @Valentino The script needs 2 arguments: 1 input and 1 output. I should have mentioned this as it is not clear in my question. I would like it to iterate over each element one-by-one, and then it should output 4 items.

Comment: "it should output 4 items". What's *it*? Do you want `sortedList[0:4]` on the first iteration, `sortedList[4:8]` on the second, etc? Or `sortedList[0:4]`, `sortedList[1:5]`, etc? Or something else?

Comment: Put another way: show a concrete value of `sortedList` with, say, 8 items, then show explicitly the calls to `subprocess.call` you want, without using a `for` loop.

Comment: @chepner the script is supposed to take in a picture pic.png, make it grayscale, and output  new.pic.png as a black and white image. I would ultimately like the script to be run over 4 different images and output 4 new images (that are now in grayscale). I apologize for the confusion and leaving out details!

Comment: So it takes 1 argument, the path of the png file. Then using just `i` instead of `i:4` in the code you posted is the solution, if the `sortedList` contains these paths. Try that. Your script should be able to rename the file.

Comment: @Valentino that makes sense, thank you. My script actually doesnt rename anything, is there a way to do that in the for loop with the subprocess call?

Comment: Yes, but how the new pic is named? I mean, if the script creates a new image, it should have a name. Or is it editing the image?

Comment: So *what is in* `sortedList`? Is it just names of files to process? Input names and output names?

Comment: @Valentino there are 4 elements in the sortedList and they are the files to process. I want the new picture to have the word "new" appended as the prefix to the original file name: pic.png -> new.pic.png. Right now, the way the script works is that it take the name of an output as the second argument. So you give it the name of the image yourself.

Comment: @chepner there are 4 elements in the sortedList and they are the files to process

Comment: Then the length of the list is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok, then @chepner has given the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is iterate over the list. You don't care (or need to know) how long that list is.

```
for i in sortedList:
    subprocess.call(['python', '/path/to/script/script.py', i, "new.{}".format(i)])
```